# Multi Store Product Sharing

Tags: magento-1.7, product, multistore, url

I have two stores, MainStore and ValentinesStore

They mainly have different products but on the ones that they share such as "Single Hearts" if I click on the product it switches stores.

From: `ValentinesStore.com/single-heart-pendants.phtml`

To: `MainStore.com/single-heart-pendants.phtml`

How do I keep them in the same store?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento Version 1.7